Can I add Custom Meta Tags to Image File in JavaScript captured on Web Camera?
I have a function in my JavaScript code that captures an image from a video stream and saves it as a file. In the mediaRecorder.onstop event handler, I convert the captured image to a file format and then to a data URL. Now, I want to manipulate the meta tags of this image file and add a custom meta tag with the key 'Source' and value 'CameraTest'. However, my attempts using the 'piexif' library have not been successful.
In the mediaRecorder.onstop event handler, after converting the image to a file and a data URL, I've tried using the 'piexif' library to manipulate the EXIF data and add custom meta tags, but I'm encountering difficulties. Is there a way to achieve this manipulation of meta tags in JavaScript, or any other library or method?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
The function:
    const captureImageManual = async () => {
        if (canvasRef && canvasRef.current && mediaStream && !captureTimer) {
            /* Record Video */
            const blobsRecorded: Blob[] = [];

            // Check if mime type is supported by browser
            for (let index = 0; index < mimeTypes.length; index += 1) {
                const isSupported = MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported(mimeTypes[index].mime);
                if (isSupported) {
                    supportedMimeType.current = mimeTypes[index];

                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!supportedMimeType?.current?.mime) {
                console.log('No valid video mime type supported by browser');
                toast.error('This browser is not supported for KYC. Please try again using a different browser.');
                Sentry.captureException({
                    error: new Error('No valid video mime type supported by browser'),
                    message: 'This browser is not supported for KYC. Please try again using a different browser.',
                });
                return;
            }

            // set MIME type of recording as the first supported mime type found
            const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStream, { mimeType: supportedMimeType.current.mime });

            // event : new recorded video blob available
            mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
                console.log('event data: ', event.data);
                blobsRecorded.push(event.data);
            };

            // event : recording stopped & all blobs sent
            mediaRecorder.onstop = async () => {
                // // create local object URL from the recorded video blobs
                // const videoLocal = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(blobsRecorded, { type: 'video/mp4' }));

                // Convert BLOB to File
                const recordedVideoFile = new File(blobsRecorded, 'video', { type: supportedMimeType.current?.mime });

                setVideoFile(recordedVideoFile);

                /* Capture Photo */
                // Add to canvas element
                // const xMultiplier = videoRef.current.videoWidth / videoRef.current.clientWidth;
                // const yMultiplier = videoRef.current.videoHeight / videoRef.current.clientHeight;
                canvasRef.current.height = videoRef?.current?.videoHeight;
                canvasRef.current.width = videoRef?.current?.videoWidth;
                canvasRef?.current
                    ?.getContext('2d')
                    ?.drawImage(videoRef.current, 0, 0, videoRef?.current?.videoWidth, videoRef?.current?.videoHeight);

                // const dimension = isDesktop ? (window.innerWidth / 100) * 20 : 260;
                // const dimension = holeRef?.current?.clientWidth;

                // canvasRef?.current?.getContext('2d')?.drawImage(
                //     videoRef.current, // image
                //     (videoRef.current.clientWidth / 2) * xMultiplier - (dimension / 2) * xMultiplier, // sx
                //     32 * yMultiplier, // sy
                //     dimension * xMultiplier, // sWidth
                //     dimension * yMultiplier, // sHeight
                //     0, // dx
                //     0, // dy
                //     canvasRef.current.width, // dWidth
                //     canvasRef.current.height, // dHeight
                // );
                const imageDataUrl = canvasRef.current.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
                setCapturedImageUrl(imageDataUrl);

                // Convert to File
                const res: Response = await fetch(imageDataUrl);
                const blob: Blob = await res.blob();
                const capturedImageFile = new File([blob], 'selfie', { type: 'image/jpeg' });

                //
                const exifIfd: any = {};
                exifIfd[piexif.ExifIFD.DateTimeOriginal] = '2010:10:10 10:10:10';
                exifIfd[piexif.ExifIFD.LensMake] = 'Lens Maker';
                exifIfd[piexif.ExifIFD.Sharpness] = 777;
                exifIfd[piexif.ExifIFD.LensSpecification] = [
                    [1, 1],
                    [1, 1],
                    [1, 1],
                    [1, 1],
                ];
                // exifIfd['Source'] = 'CameraTestPotlee';

                const exifBytes = piexif.dump({ Exif: exifIfd });
                const exifModified = piexif.insert(exifBytes, imageDataUrl);

                setSrc(exifModified);

                console.log({ exifModified });

                // const newFile = await writePNGtext(capturedImageFile, 'Source', 'CameraTestPotlee');
                // const buffer = new Uint8Array([newFile]);
                // const blobx = new Blob([buffer], { type: 'image/png' }); // Specify the file type
                // const filex = new File([blobx], 'selfie', { type: 'image/png' }); // Specify filename and type

                // const exifrParse = await exifr.parse(filex);
                // const metaTags = await EXIF.getAllTags(filex);
                // console.log({ metaTags });

                setSelfieFile(capturedImageFile);
            };
            // event : recording started
            mediaRecorder.onstart = () => {
                // Capture button timer
                setCaptureTimer(3);
                interval.current = setInterval(() => {
                    setCaptureTimer((state) => {
                        if (state > 0) {
                            return state - 1;
                        }
                        return state;
                    });
                }, 1000);

                // Stop recording after 3 seconds
                setTimeout(() => {
                    mediaRecorder.stop();
                }, 3000);
                setNewImage(true);
            };
            // start recording with each recorded blob having 1 second video
            mediaRecorder.start(1000);
        }
    };

I tried using different libraries like: piexifjs, exif-js, exifr, image-metadata-editor
But mostly I was not able to add any custom tag.
